# WCF excluding datamembers to be serialized in the Derived class

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have the following classes. I want do not want the derived class to serialize "Name", however, the following code does not seem to work. if I declare an instance of the derived class, the "Name" property still gets serialized..

```
[DataContract]
public class Base
{
  [DataMember]
  public virtual string Name
  {get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Derived: Base
{
   [IgnoreDataMember]
   public override string Name
   {get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you declare the property virtual in the Base class? And then override it in the derived class

Comment: Thanks. it was a typo, I did declare it virtual in my Base class, and override in my Derived class. It doesnt work. still serializes "Name" :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `ScriptIgnore` (json) or `XmlIgnore` (xml) attributes, depending on what you're serializing to. That should prevent that member from being serialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to use XmlSerializer here is the code

```
public class Base
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual  string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    [XmlIgnore] //Remove this to include
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Derived));
xmlSer.Serialize(memStream, new Derived() { Name = "aaaa" });
MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.ToArray()));
```