# .Net Doesn't Serialize Enumeration In SOAP

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I have created a WCF service (A-end) which (B-end) is using and they are developing some new services which again A-end has to consume.
The issue is some of the properties are not serialized on B-end when we hit their services.
They are declaring all the class object what we have exposed.
I have noticed in-service class that there is an attribute with those specific parameters.
i.e. `system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute()`

What can be the issue is that those properties can be seen in code while I am assigning values to them but they are not being seen at receiving end?

***A-end: The development is done in .Net (WCF Services)
B-end: Some IBM tool
A-end: consuming B-end services and they are not receiving some of the fields.***

Comment: If I understood you correctly, this might give some insights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041112/wcf-excluding-datamembers-to-be-serialized-in-the-derived-class

Comment: You can put DataContractAttribute on your class, and DataMemberAttribute on any properties you wish to have serialized if these attributes are not serialized.

Comment: @KlausGütter Well Let me explain more, my attribute is not seen when I convert my class object into serialize method.